# Setting state variables on the client side in SignalR

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, signalr

I'm using the javascript library to connect to a signalR server being hosted in a console app.

Therefore I connect and set client methods which can be called from the server like so:

```
var connection = $.hubConnection('http://localhost:8080'),
    proxy = connection.createHubProxy('TestApp');

proxy.on('sendMessage', function () {
    // do stuff!
});
```

which is described in detail [here](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/SignalR-JS-Client-Hubs-%28No-Proxy%29).

However, the documentation for using the client side javascript in this manner doesn't explain how to round-trip information (set the 'state' variable on the client side and have it accessible from the server).

It's probably pretty obvious, but any help will be much appreciated!

Also, there is something which I think is closely related that I'm curious about. I know the client side code can get a return value/callback after calling a function on the server like so (from the documentation linked above)

```
proxy.invoke('add', 1, 2)
     .done(function(result) {
         console.log('The result is ' + result);
     });
```

but is it possible for the server to get a callback from the client when the client finished a task? (Obviously just having a the client trigger a predefined event solves this problem, but it would be nice to handle all callback without having to setup another event if this is possible.)

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1)**
For setting state it's as simple as:

```
proxy.state.foo = 1337;
```

Then of course you can get this on the server via

```
int myFoo = Clients.Caller.foo;
```

**2)**
No you are unable to be notified on the server when a client side function has finished executing.  If you're trying to know when a client side function has finished you can simply call back to the server yourself.

For instance:

```
proxy.on('foo', function(){
    console.log("Foo executed");
    proxy.invoke("fooDone");
});
```

You'd then need to create a "fooDone" function on the server to handle the callback.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I actually tried setting proxy.state directly before posting, but now that I think about it, it may have failed because I was trying to read Clients.Caller.foo during the onConnect event on the server hub. Perhaps it just can't be called from that event? Another possible reason it could have failed for me is that I set the state on the client before the connection is made (same place where I set proxy.on(...) before starting the connection)?

Comment: It doesn't matter when you set the state but you are only able to read the state on method invocations on the server.  Therefore yes, you are correct you cannot read the state in OnConnected, OnDisconnected, OnReconnected